# AttrributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'org' when trying to filter a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to filter a dataframe of logs generated by one of our applications. Basically, the code look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''{"a": 1, "b": 2, "context": {"org": "company_1", "user": ""}}
{"a": 3, "b": 4, "context": {"org": "", "user": "test"}}
{"a": 5, "b": 6, "context": {"user": "test_2"}}'''

df = pd.load_json(data, lines = True)

filtered_data = df[df.context.org == 'company_1']
```

Unfortunately, this code throws an exception:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'org'

I can understand the exception since the third line of the data doesn't have the context.org set.

However, there are no ways I can 'fix' the data before trying to filter them (here we are talking about a couple of millions of lines of log).

Is there a way to tell pandas to simply ignore the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by dictionaries with selecting by `get` which working also if not exist key `org`:

```
df1 = df[df['context'].apply(lambda x: x.get('org') == 'company_1')]
#alternative
#df1 = df[[x.get('org') == 'company_1' for x in df['context']]]
print (df1)
   a  b                           context
0  1  2  {'org': 'company_1', 'user': ''}
```

But better is create columns from values of dictionaries and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), because many pandas vectorized functions not working with dictionaries in column:

```
df = pd.read_json(data, lines = True)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('context').values.tolist(), index=df.index))
print (df)

   a  b        org    user
0  1  2  company_1        
1  3  4               test
2  5  6        NaN  test_2

df2 = df2[df2['org'] == 'company_1']
print (df2)
   a  b        org user
0  1  2  company_1
```

Comment: thanks for providing 2 solution. Even though I find solution 2 'cleaner', I opted for solution 1 because it does not change the structure of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Using `concat`

```
pd.concat([df[['a','b']],pd.DataFrame(df.context.tolist(),index=df.index)],1)
Out[318]: 
   a  b        org    user
0  1  2  company_1        
1  3  4               test
2  5  6        NaN  test_2
```